# Foolproof user input program using scanner

Tags: java

This method is part of a bigger program which asks for specific user input and i need this method to prompt the user for input until its correct. here is what i have

```
public static String validName(Scanner input, Scanner histogram) {
    String user = "";
    String name = input.next();
    boolean test = false;
    while (histogram.hasNext()) {
        user = histogram.next();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(user)) {
            test = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            test = false;

        }
    }
    if (!test) {
        System.out.println("Name not found");
    }
    return user;
}
```

Scanner histogram is reading a txt file. So far it works fine, but as it is it only goes through once.

What can i change or add to make it work properly?

Comment: So you want to keep asking the user until he enters something that is in the histogram?

Comment: exactly @ksmonkey123

Comment: how "big" is your histogram? is it small enough to read in and hold in RAM completely?

Comment: ok. check out my answer below once I finish writing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick fix. Create a temporary `Scanner` and set it equal to `histogram` before you run through `histogram`. If the user is found then `validName()` will return that user, if not then repeat this function by passing in `input` and the copy of histogram `tmp`. This will get the job done but is not the right way to go about this task.

### Updated

Create a temporary string and add each user to the string followed by a space. If the check fails then recall the function with an anonymous `Scanner` constructed with the string of users.

```
public static String validName(Scanner input, Scanner histogram) {
    String user = "";
    String name = input.next();
    String tmp = "";
    boolean test = false;
    
    while (histogram.hasNext()) {
        user = histogram.next();
        tmp += user + " ";
        
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(user)) {
            test = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            test = false;

        }
    }
    if (!test) {
        System.out.println("Name not found");
        user = validName(input, new Scanner(tmp));
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: This works at re prompting the user for input, but everytime it outpus "name not found" regardless if the input is correct or not

Comment: oh my fault, `Scanner tmp = histogram` didn't clone `histogram`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It works, but for some reason, if the name is invalid(does not exist) it takes a really long time to output the name not found string. Maybe its just my computer?

Comment: It's not your computer :) the while loop has to run through ~170KB of data before outputting "Name not found". @ksmonkey123 is right to use a `HashMap` for this but not a local variable in a function, it would make more since to populate a class member `HashMap` once and make calls to that `HashMap` from the function.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, as for the hashmap the assigment does not allow me to use it. i guess u forgot to mention that in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Scanner's `findInLine(String pattern)` method, try the following:

```
public static String validName(Scanner input, Scanner histogram) {
String user = "";
String name = input.next();

 if(histogram.findInLine(name) != null){
  System.out.println("This name exist");//Do what you have to do here
 }
 else{
  System.out.println("Name not found");
  user = validName(input, histogram);
 }
return user;
}
```

Take a look at [the Scanner Class methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a perfect solution, but here's how i would do it: first read the complete histogramm into a hash Table. This allows for very efficient input validation later on:

```
public static String validName(Scanner input, Scanner histogram) {
    HashSet<String> validInputs = new HashSet<>();

    // read in histogram
    while (histogram.hasNext())
        validInputs.add(histogram.next());

    // ask for input and repeat if necessary
    while (true) {
        String userInput = input.next();
        if (validInputs.contains(userInput))
            return userInput;
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
}
```

i've not tested this solution but it should work.
Also the histogram is only ever read once. After that only the hash values of the different Strings are compared. Since 2 Strings with the same content should always have the same hash value this should work.

Also this solution does not require any recursion.

Comment: Using a `HashSet` would make more sense as a class member. Creating and populating a `HashSet` for each call to `#validName` seams like a lot of overhead.

Comment: of course if several inputs were to be checked, this could be cached as a class member.
I just wanted to point out a solution that allows for efficient precence checking in a large list.